# Opening IE tab for bunch of URLs from txt file

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am using following powershell to open bunch of urls. the script only opens the first url and then gives following error. Any idea why? I am using Windows 7 and IE 11.

Error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Navigate2'.
```

Code

```
Function Open-IETabs { 
   param ( 
   [string[]]$Url    )
   begin { 
   $Ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application    } 
   process {
   $navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
   foreach ($Link in $Url) 
   {
    write-host $Link
   $Ie.Navigate2($Link, $navOpenInBackgroundTab) 
   }   
   }    
   end 
   {        
   $Ie.Visible = $true    }
   }
#$path = read-host 'Enter the path of ppm list file'
$path = "c:\texturl.txt"
$url = gc $path


Open-IETabs -Url $Url
```

Comment: That's weird. It works for me without any errors. It just opens one more tab (MSIE's home page). I have also Windows 7 (64-bit), PowerShell 4.0, MSIE 11.

Comment: Thanks Dawid for confirming. Do i need to add trust or something? could it be group policy?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. It's weird, that it once works.

Comment: If I move this $Ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application right above $Ie.Navigate2 then it works but it opens IE by itself and I get 84 IE windows.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the code is good and PowerShell needs to be open as Administrator.

Comment: Weird, it works without elevating PowerShell to the Administrator for me.

Comment: Yes, running the script as an admin resolved this issue for me. Also using Windows 7 and IE11.